# Jersey resource filters and OPTIONS method

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I use Jersey for RESTful api in my application. I have some Resource, annotated with @ResourceFilters(value=...). Everything works fine with methods, declared in resource, but when I try to make OPTIONS request, filters do not work.
Is there any way to make filters work for my case, or I need to declare explicit OPTIONS method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResourceFilter is really meant for filtering execution of resource methods. If you don't define OPTIONS method explicitly, the HTTP call does not get mapped to a resource method (is handled implicitly). You can use [ContainerRequestFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) for that case.